# Prove that centralizers of regular elements are abelian

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a complex semisimple Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. In a particular [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209053) (first paragraph), the following statement is made:

> If $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ is regular (i.e. has centralizer of minimal dimension) then
>   $$
> Z_G(X) := \{g\in G:\mathrm{Ad}_gX=X\},
> $$
>   is abelian.

However, no justification is given, and I was wondering if anybody knows how to prove it or can point a reference discussing this.

**What I know:** The Lie algebra of $Z_G(X)$ is the centralizer $Z_{\mathfrak{g}}(X)$ of $X$ in $\mathfrak{g}$. Since $X$ is regular, $Z_{\mathfrak{g}}(X)$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. In particular, $Z_{\mathfrak{g}}(X)$ is abelian and hence the identity component of $Z_G(X)$ is abelian. Thus, it suffices to show that $Z_G(X)/(Z_G(X))^\circ$ is abelian.

Comment: I know I'm terribly late. This might be related: We say $f \in \mathfrak g^*$ is regular if $g^f := \{ x \in \mathfrak g | f([x,y]) = 0 \forall y \in \mathfrak g \}$. Proposition 1.11.7 in Dixmier _Enveloping Algebras_ "Let $f$ be a regular element in $\mathfrak g^*$. The the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g^f$ is commutative". Later it is also proved that for semisimple Lie algebras, centralizer of $x \in \mathfrak g$ equals $g^f$ if $f$ is the corresponding element of $x$ in $g^*$ by the Killing isomorphism.